# How do I create if statements in php to perform a specific action depending on what form has string in it

Tags: php, forms, variables

Im trying to create a grid on my page in each cell there will be a simple one line form.  If a person enters data into lets say FieldA I would like the php to perform actionA but if the data was entered in FieldF I would like actionF performed.  Is this possible without having to create a php for each cell and upload all those php files?

Or is there a way to perform the GET method in each form to append the data to the end of the action url without the field name showing (ie sample.com/somestuff/fieldA instead of sample.com/somestuff/fieldname=fieldA)   thus not needing php at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a little ambiguous to me. I'll give it a shot though.

On the form I would set:

```
`method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>"`
```

This will cause the form to submit back to itself.  Then at the top of the page you could do something like the following:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["fieldA"]){
        performActionA();
    } else if (isset($_POST["fieldB"]){
        performActionB();
    }
    etc...
?>
```

Is that what you are trying to do?  Keep in mind php is executed server side before any interaction with the user.

otherwise you could use javascript to change the action field of the form.  (Untested)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setAction(elt){
      var page = document.getElementById(elt).value;
      document.myform.action="sample.com/somestuff/"+page;
  }
</script>

<form id="myform" action="sample.com/somestuff/">
   <input type="text" name="text1" onchange="setAction('text1')" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah I need it to be performed server side, so I will try the php coding and see if that works, but how would I list the actions.  What Im trying to do is set each field to have its own url with the field string as a variable added to its specific URL if that makes. any more since.   Just trying to find a way of doing it without having to make a bunch of php docs

Answer (score 0):

Did you try anything. Please try to write some code. If you get struck paste the code here, somebody will help you out..

In my opinion, why you need different forms. Just have a form which has n text boxes and perform the task that you need.

Comment: here is a sample coding if I where to make a php for each form

<form method="post" action=first.php target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="first" /><br />
</form>

<form method="post" action=second.php target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="first" /><br />
</form>

<form method="post" action=third.php target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="first" /><br />
</form>

<form method="post" action=fourth.php target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="first" /><br />
</form>

<form method="post" action=fifth.php target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="first" /><br />
</form>

Comment: I would like to have just one php file that can execute an action depending on which form was filled out.  Thats where Im stuck

Comment: If you can do it with a single form, what is the need of creating separate forms for each field. Its a tedious process

Comment: because each form has a different dynamic url